# Searching string for multiple keywords efficiently PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am currently trying to search multiple strings per second with 1000's of keywords. Until recently everything was ok using some regex which I can post but was probably very bad. What methods can I use? I've read a bit about trie's but not sure if these suit my needs?

```
// 100 strings per second
// 100 characters long average
foreach ($stringSet as $haystack) {
    // 10000 keywords
    // 10 characters long average and can be multiple words
    $matches = stringContains($needles, $haystack)
    // Do stuff with matches
}
```

The regex (doesn't quite fit with previous code because that was sort of pseudo):

```
function stringContains($needles, $haystack) {
    $matchingTerms = array();
    $matches = array();
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        $needle = preg_split('/([^[:alnum:]])+/u',$needle);
        $needle = implode('',$needle);
        $needle  = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $needle);
        $pattern = implode('[^[:alnum:]]*', $needle);
        $pattern = '/\b'.$pattern.'\b/iu';

        preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches);
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $matchingTerms = array_merge($matchingTerms, $match);
        }
    }
    return $matchingTerms;
}
```

Comment: Knowing more problem parameters will help. Do the haystacks change frequently? Are they always the same? Why do you have so many keywords? If a brute force full text search is too slow then you need to optimize, and optimizing is all about which compromises you can deal with.

Comment: @NickC Yes I recieve approximately 100 haystacks a second and they are approximately 100 characters each and they need to be compared against 1000's of keywords.

Comment: Maybe you can try using database to implement this as database do searching a bit quicker then PHP

Comment: @MichaelMitch I am currently using redis as my main db so do you know of any already existing solutions for this?

Comment: I would implode and separate your word boundaries by pipe delimeter.

Comment: ＠adamjg I am not familiar with redis, but you can try start reading this: http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2011/06/writing-simple-keyword-search-engine.html for inverted index and stemming for searching.

Comment: @hwnd Thanks I will try that out, could you also expand please?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following maybe.

```
function stringContains($needles, $haystack) {    
   $matchingTerms = array();
   $matches = array();

   foreach ($needles as $needle) {
      $pattern = "/\b(" . implode('|', $needle) . ")\b/i";
      $found   = preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches);

      if ($found) {
        $keys = array_unique($matches[0]);
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
           $matchingTerms = array_merge($matchingTerms, $key);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this shortly. Did you mean to but everything within that for loop. Not sure if its going to provide the performance increase I need as this function will be need to be called 100 times a second with atleast 1000 keywords.

Comment: Try it out and see what happens. This is all your loop should include.

Comment: Thanks hwnd, that made a small difference so now the queue is not growing as fast, it is however still growing. I need a really clever solution something like a tree search or something

Comment: Another way is put the set on a database into a field type text and implement a fulltext search, will be more faster and the result can be more accurate.